# Where is boost::lambda::ll?

Tags: boost, foreach, boost-lambda

I can't seem to find boost::lambda::ll for a nested ll::for_each() invocations in any  header file in the boost_1_39_0 distribution. Could someone point me to the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boost_1_39_0/boost/lambda/algorithm.hpp

first structure defined there is boost::lambda::ll::for_each